# Adding Click handler to existing subclassed Textview control

Tags: android, textview, subclassing

looking at using this to add some "tags" to my UI:

https://github.com/mcharmas/android-tagview

It does most of what I need, but I do need the tags to be clickable.  What would be the best approach to create a fork of this that added clickable (in my case a web URL) to this?

Not looking for a full solution (I like to work things things out myself as part of learning), but I wouldn't mind being pointed in the right direction at the start.

Many thanks.

Comment: You would need to implement a ClickableSpan. The library seems to turn the tags into spans, you just need to also implement a ClickableSpan over the text.

Comment: Many thanks.  Will attempt this.